# Open URL on open port

Tags: go

I'm assuming I can run a [service on port 3000](https://github.com/kaihendry/lk/blob/05b4db2aa670ddc58761a79db22e3a806a0085ce/main.go#L76) like many other [code samples I've seen on Github](https://github.com/search?q=http.ListenAndServe+open.Start&ref=simplesearch&type=Code).

Now I am trying to improve my code so that it looks for an open port in case 3000 is in use:

```
for port := 3000; port <= 3005; port++ {
    fmt.Println(port)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+strconv.Itoa(port), nil)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("lk is serving", dirPath, "from http://0.0.0.0:", string(port))
        open.Start("http://0.0.0.0:" + string(port))
    }
}
```

However it blocks on the **http.ListenAndServe** line and doesn't **open.Start** my browser. I'm told I should use goroutines but I am still a bit bewildered how to use them in this context.

This is a "client" Web app so I do need it to invoke my browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling ListenAndServe, create the [Listener](https://godoc.org/net#Listener) in the application and then call [Serve](http://godoc.org/net/http#Serve).  When creating the listener, request a free port by specifying the listener address as ":0":

```
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":0")
if err != nil {
     // handle error
}
```

Once the listener is open, you can start the browser:

```
open.Start("http://" + ln.Addr().String())
```

and then start the server:

```
if err := http.Serve(ln, nil); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```

There's no need to use a goroutine.

The code above uses [addr.String()](http://godoc.org/net#Addr.String) to format the listener's address. If you do need to get the port number for some reason, use a type assertion:

```
if a, ok := ln.Addr().(*net.TCPAddr); ok {
   fmt.Println("port", a.Port)
}
```

Comment: Where can I find the usage of `:0` ?

Comment: But I can't found the document of this usage

Comment: The port number is passed to the kernel where the allocation occurs. The handling of port zero in kernels is so mundane that I don't think it's documented anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! excellent excellent answer. https://github.com/kaihendry/lk/commit/023a060161be186ff4d29535ccf6df29009243b7 Would be awesome if you could please review https://github.com/kaihendry/lk/

Comment: With addr.String(), I wish it returned the hostname instead of [::].